# Windows live api for python

Tags: python, hotmail

I have read documentation about Windows Live API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx

But how can I retrieve contacts from hotmail with python ?

Is there any example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program will first need to obtain "delegated authentication", for which the Python samples are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287653.aspx).

After that, the interface is REST-like: you only need to HTTP GET the appropriate URI (per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463933.aspx), that's '/LiveContacts/contacts' to retrieve all contacts.  The REST Schema is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463953.aspx).  You can make an HTTP GET request in Python with such standard library modules as urllib and urllib2, though the lower-level httplib module is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for the download link for the library
http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/a/62adfe67-6fee-487f-9c3e-911ce5d0bc9d/webauth-python-1.2.tar.gz